# Dynamic load video in Jquery Slider in the website

Tags: jquery, html, video, jquery-ui-slider

I am currently stuck with an issue in the website I have designed.

```
<div class="slider-pro" id="my-slider">
                <iframe width="1920" height="1280" src="youtubevideoURL?rel=0&fs=1&showinfo=0&autohide=1&vq=hd1080&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=playlistId" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

But with this what is happening is - the video is always getting downloaded into the user's browser even when the slide is not clicked and shown.

I have 6 slides in the slider and 3 of them have such video links. I want to load the video on demand ( on demand event being the slide is the one that is currently active).

I am using jquery.sliderPro plugin in the website.

Can anyone please provide me some insights as to how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the autoplay parameter from the **src**.
This is what your code should look like-

```
 <iframe width="1920" height="1280" src="youtubevideoURL?rel=0&fs=1&showinfo=0&autohide=1&vq=hd1080&loop=1&playlist=playlistId" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```